# Java - Having difficulty with the movement of an Object for my Semester Project

Tags: java, project

I'm in the middle of doing my project for this semesters class, and it's basically a very simple Rogue Like game.
I'm having trouble making this Object (a Bat) stop moving when it tries to jump to the players (Hero) location and attack instead, but it still overlaps with the players sprite.
The first code belongs to the Bat class and the second is the main Rogue class that starts the game. There's also a ImageMatrixGUI class that implements the game window and sprites.
Thank you in advance.

```
private static final int HP=3;
private static final int DAMAGE=1;

public Bat(Point2D position) {
    super(position);
    setHP(HP);
    setDamage(DAMAGE);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public int getLayer() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 1;
}

@Override
public void move() {
    Random ran = new Random();
    int i = ran.nextInt(2);
    if(i==0) {
        Vector2D v = Vector2D.movementVector(getPosition(), Rogue.getInstance().getHeroPosition());
        if(getPosition().plus(v) == Rogue.getInstance().getHeroPosition()) {
            attack(getPosition().plus(v));
            v = new Vector2D(0,0);
        }
        setPosition(getPosition().plus(v));
    }else {
        Point2D nextP = getPosition().plus(Direction.random().asVector());
        if(nextP == Rogue.getInstance().getHeroPosition()) {
            attack(nextP);
            nextP = new Point2D(0,0);
        }
        if(nextP.getX()<1 || nextP.getY()<1 || nextP.getX()>8 || nextP.getY()>8)
            nextP=getPosition();
        setPosition(nextP);
    }

}

@Override
public void attack(Point2D p) {
    Rogue.getInstance().dealDamage(DAMAGE);
}
```

}

```
private static final Rogue INSTANCE = new Rogue();

// Singleton pattern: private constructor
private Rogue() {
    // Do not delete/change or move these three lines
    ImageMatrixGUI.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT + 1); // +1 because last row is the status bar
    ImageMatrixGUI.getInstance().registerObserver(this);
    ImageMatrixGUI.getInstance().setStatusMessage("Rogue Game Test"); // Try other message, keep track of the room number using this message

    // staticInit() should be replaced by initFromFile(FILENAME); after first phase with FILENAME = "config/map.txt"
    staticInit(); 
}

// Singleton pattern inspector
public static Rogue getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
}

// Initialization for 1st phase 
private void staticInit() {
    hero = new Hero(new Point2D(1,1));
    skeleton = new Skeleton(new Point2D(WIDTH-2, 1));
    bat = new Bat(new Point2D(1, HEIGHT-2));
    sword = new Sword(new Point2D(WIDTH-2, HEIGHT-2));
    for(int w=0; w<WIDTH; w++) {
        for(int h=0; h<=HEIGHT; h++) {
            if(h<HEIGHT)
                ImageMatrixGUI.getInstance().addImage(new Floor(new Point2D(w,h)));
            if(w<WIDTH-3 && h==HEIGHT) {
                ImageMatrixGUI.getInstance().addImage(new Green(new Point2D(w,h)));
                ImageMatrixGUI.getInstance().addImage(new Black(new Point2D(w+3,h)));
            }
        }
    }
    for(int w=0; w<WIDTH; w++) {
        for(int h=0; h<=HEIGHT-1; h++) {
            ImageMatrixGUI.getInstance().addImage(new Wall(new Point2D(w,h)));
            if(w!=0 && w!=WIDTH-1)
                h+=HEIGHT-2;
        }

    }

    ImageMatrixGUI.getInstance().addImage(hero);
    ImageMatrixGUI.getInstance().addImage(skeleton);
    ImageMatrixGUI.getInstance().addImage(bat);
    ImageMatrixGUI.getInstance().addImage(sword);

    // TODO: Initialize other objects in the appropriate lists (use a Factory to make switch to file-based initialization easy)

}

// Starting-up GUI
public void go() {
    ImageMatrixGUI.getInstance().go();
    ImageMatrixGUI.getInstance().update();      
}

public Point2D getHeroPosition() {
    return hero.getPosition();
}

public void dealDamage(int i) {
    hero.getDamaged(i);
}

public int getTurn() {
    return turn;
}

public int getWidth() {
    return WIDTH;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return HEIGHT;
}

// Called everytime a key is pressed
@Override
public void update(Observed source) {
    int keyPressed = ImageMatrixGUI.getInstance().keyPressed();
    Direction d = Direction.directionFor(keyPressed);
    hero.move(d);
    skeleton.move();
    bat.move();
    turn++;

    //TODO: what else?

    ImageMatrixGUI.getInstance().update();
}
```

Comment: Where are you taking into account the width of your sprite?

Comment: Also, is it possible that `getPosition() < Rogue.getInstance().getHeroPosition()` while `getPosition().plus(v) > Rogue.getInstance().getHeroPosition()` (or vice versa)?

Comment: @JoeC the dimensions of all the sprites are the same, and move by the same amount, all that being in the ImageMatrixGUI class that's provided by the teacher and that i can't touch.
On your second suggestion, getPosition() and getHeroPosition() return a Point2D(x,y) that can't be used with > or <